# iPhone: change UITableView cells paint order

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I need to change paint order by z axis, so always middle cell is on top. Anyone know any method which let me to change repaint order?

What I have now (white row is set to selected and shows which one is middle (should be on top in z axis)):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution myself. Just called `[mTableView bringSubviewToFront:cell];` for middle row and it works fine. I didn't try it before, because on android it didn't work. I had to change paint order (android sdk have protected method for that).

Hope this helps to someone